# Expand jar with native libs

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to set up JNotify on OS X, i know that i need to include the native lib to the project and use the `java.library.path`.

I tried to add the *jnotify.so* to the path, and configured the Virtual Machine launch with java `-Djava` with no success so far.

Comment: I think it is a liitle bit diferent with OSX: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1170/_index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the official site says

> Note that java.library.path should point to the location of the native libraries that comes with jnotify

So if you extract the `.so` file next to the jar, this should work:

```
java -Djava.library.path=. -jar jnotify-VER.jar [dir]
```

Comment: It was more a problem managing natives from IDE than other thing.